# How to upload a document in a SharePoint list using Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, microsoft-graph, c-sharp, azure-ad-graph-api

We have been trying to add a document to a list item using Graph API but are being thrown a 400 error :( We have the access token and can query the list in question without any problem. Below is the code we are using to try to add the document to the list

```
string addItemJsonString = "{\"fields\":{\"Title\":\"Dec Word file\"}}";

string requestUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mysite.sharepoint.com:/sites/mySite:/lists/My Library/items";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl);
message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
message.Content = new StringContent(addItemJsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); //set the body for the request


client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
else
  responseString = "Error in response";
```

Any idea of where we are losing it?

Comment: Do you want to add a list item to a list, or upload a document as your title describes?

Comment: We want to upload a document as an attachment to the list item. The use case is that the list item describes the searchable meta data of the document.

Comment: Please consider using a document set or a document library to provide metadata to documents instead. I'm not familiar with your specific use-case, but my very best advice to you is to as far as it's possible, avoid list item attachments for file storage.

Comment: We can use a document library. I always thought the two use the same structure. Do you think the above code will work if we change the underlying structure from list to library?

Answer (score 1):

In reference to the comments, if you want to upload a document to a SharePoint Online Document Library using Microsoft Graph, you should start with the [ListItem](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/listitem)  endpoint.

Note the end of the documentation where it specifies that for document libraries, a ListItem is exposed as a [driveItem](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveItem).

To upload to the driveItem, you should have two options. If your files are less than 4MB, issue a `PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content` with the binary contents in the body of the request. 
This is documented [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_put_content).

For files over 4MB, you must use establish an UploadSession as documented [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createuploadsession). 
Basically, you issue a `POST /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession` to create the session, and an `uploadUrl` will be returned to you. You can then issue a

```
PUT https://<uplod url>
Content-Length: 26
Content-Range: bytes 0-25/128

<bytes 0-25 of the file>
```

Comment: Helge my friend - We have incorporated your suggestion but still are running into bad request exception. One thing that we are not clear about is {parent-id} attribute of the request. What exactly needs to replace this tag? This maybe where we are losing it.

Answer (score 0):

To upload an small item (`<4MB`) into a SharePoint Online document library or list which is not the default library, you can use the following `URL` syntax:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{SITE-ID}/drives/{DRIVE-ID}/root:/{FILENAME}:/content
```

- `{SITE-ID}`: the ID of SP site
- `{DRIVE-ID}`: the ID of drive (document library or list)
- `{FILENAME}`: the name of the fie to upload

The `"/root:"` after the drive ID is the important point.